# Concatenation operator in System verilog in a loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, concatenation, system-verilog

I am trying to do the following : `concat = {concat[7:0],clk}` inside a forever loop as below :

```
   bit [7:0]    concat;
   concat = 0;
   forever begin
        @(posedge clk);
        concat = {concat[7:0],clk};
    end
```

I wanted to know what value will it contain after 8 clock iterations at any point of time, if the initial value of `concat = 0`.

Can it be different from `'hAA` or `'h55` at any point of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `@(posdege clk)`, `clk` will always be 1 (or x) when evaluating the RHS of the assignment. So concat will be 'h00, 'h01, 'h03, 'h07, 'h17, ...

Also note that if any other thread tries to read `concat` on the same positive edge of clk, you have a race condition, so please use a NBA to make the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can not just write `concat = 0;` you should either `assign concat = 0;` or

```
initial begin
  concat = 0;
end
```

Forever can not be used like that, the only two top levels you're allowed are `initial` and `always`. You want some thing like the following for a simulation:

```
initial begin
  forever begin
    @(posedge clk);
    concat = {concat[6:0],clk};
  end
end
```

If you are writing for synthesis then you might want to imply a flip-flop:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  concat = {concat[6:0],clk};
end
```

Once you have fixed your RTL it should be easy to try out on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/FU7).

Comment: Thank you for replying Morgan.
Assume that everything is fine, the above (similar)piece of code is used in a UVM testbench. I just wanted to know what would be the output because I am not able to debug this using uvm_info macro as it is being used in an if condition which is not occurring. Any pointer would be appreciated

Comment: @user3714538 The block only triggers or waits for on `posedge of clk` ie clk is 1. Therefore concat will slowly fill up with 1's, after 8 clks will always be `FF`.